# Is it possible to pause the auto changing image in view flipper with a touch

Tags: viewflipper

Is it possible to pause the auto changing image with a finger touch in view flipper. Here I have given a product 360 view with some images , now I want to give the users a facility to pause and see the image .

Below given is the current XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_kten_seeround"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".KtenSeeround">
    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/flipper1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:autoStart="true"
        android:flipInterval="500"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/image1"
            android:src="@drawable/kten75"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/image2"
            android:src="@drawable/kten70"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/image3"
            android:src="@drawable/kten65"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/image4"
            android:src="@drawable/kten60"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/image5"
            android:src="@drawable/kten55"/>

    </ViewFlipper>

</RelativeLayout>
```